# Weird Overlay draw behaviour when zooming in the MapView

Tags: android, overlay, zooming, android-mapview

I've extended Overlay and implemented `draw()` in order to draw some stuff onto the map.
When zooming is done through `mapController.zoomIn()` (called when doubleTapping the map),
the overlay is drawn properly onto the map.

But whenever I zoom in/out with the built in zoom controller, the overlay is not drawn properly and panning the map is needed to get the overlay refreshed.

Comment: Did you (or anyone else) find a solution to this? It's been driving me batty for months.

Comment: The workaround I found was to refresh the map only after 500ms that the map was zoomed, this way the overlay is drawn after the map has already been zoomed. I add the event with Handler.postDelayed(). Hope this helps

Comment: I have been using MapView for quite sometime, not noticed this issue. If possible, please post your code/flow to understand the logic better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use zoom controller and get rid of this problem..
(ex: zoomView = (LinearLayout) mapView.getZoomControls(); )

check with this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ZoomButtonsController.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.getController().setZoom(15);

    controller = mapView.getController();




    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
```

this.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using zoom controllers with no problem at all.
even having drawn multi layers on the map and zoom in/out has no bad effect at all.

I suggest to use as below

```
mapController = mapView.getController();
mapController.zoomIn();// or .zoomOut()
```

instead of using setZoom(XX) please use zoomIn() / zoomOut() which makes zooming smoother, this may help making it work better esp with multiple overlays.

Answer (score 1):

I've found in my mapview app that I want to track my own position, so in the code I set a geopoint to my current gps position,then I use the following code to move the map center to that point and found that it works wonderfully:

```
MapController mc = mapView.getController(); 
               mc.animateTo(point);
```

You could create a function which zooms and animates to the overlay point. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I created a lot of custom drawables in my map view. Unfortunately the drawables expanded when zoomed out (when they should have shrunk). To get around this, I monitored the user zooming in or out in a runnable. If the zoom changed, I redrew the map. Here is my code:

```
private Runnable zoomChecker = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        //check for updates
        if((mLastUpdate>UPDATE_INTERVAL)&&(!DISPLAY_RED_CIRCLE)&&(!DISPLAY_ROUTE_LAYOUT)){
            updateRouteInformation();
            mLastUpdate = 0; 
        }else{
            mLastUpdate += 200;
        }
        //check for zoom level changes
        int testZoomLevel = mMapView.getZoomLevel();
        if((testZoomLevel!=mZoomLevel)&&(DISPLAY_RED_CIRCLE)){
            //set that user is zooming 
            mStillZooming = true;

            //remove overlays and clear map
            removeOverlayItems();       
            mMapView.invalidate();

            //set zoom level as same
            mZoomLevel = testZoomLevel;
        }
        if((testZoomLevel==mZoomLevel)&&(mStillZooming)){
            displayDriverBoundaries(MAP_DRIVER);
        }
        handler.removeCallbacks(zoomChecker); // remove the old callback
        handler.postDelayed(zoomChecker, zoomCheckingDelay); // register a new one
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyMap_MapControllerActivity extends MapActivity {

    private MapView mapView;
    //private MapController mapController;
     MapView.LayoutParams lp;
     int y = 10;
        int x = 10;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
        mapView.setStreetView(true);
        mapView.setTraffic(true);



    GeoPoint center = mapView.getMapCenter();
    int latSpan = mapView.getLatitudeSpan();
    int longSpan = mapView.getLongitudeSpan();




    lp = new MapView.LayoutParams(MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    x, y,
    MapView.LayoutParams.TOP_LEFT);
    View zoomControls = mapView.getZoomControls();
    mapView.addView(zoomControls, lp);
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
    }



    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    }
```